# SQL. How to select unique records from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, unique

I need to select unique columns with unique records. For now, after pivot, when I use simple query `SELECT * FROM table` I got results like that:

```
| Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | -- column names
|   1   |  1    |   1   |   2   |   2   |   2   |   3   |   3   |   3   | -- records
```

---

If I use query: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table` I got following results:

```
| Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | -- different column names
|   1   |   1   |   1   | -- unique records
```

---

It should be like that:

```
| Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | -- different column names
|   1   |   2   |   3   | -- different records
```

Have you ideas?

P.s. Records are dynamic

---

**UPDATE:**

I'm using in real so confused select before pivoting to give different names for columns, maybe you have suggestion how to make different names in other way?

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 @colsConversion +=    'CAST([' + Name+ '] AS ' + 'NVARCHAR(MAX)' + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME('Test'+'1')+ ',' + 
                                            'CAST([' + Name+ '] AS ' + 'NVARCHAR(MAX)' + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME('Test'+'2')+ ',' + 
                                            'CAST([' + Name+ '] AS ' + 'NVARCHAR(MAX)' + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME('Test'+'3')+ ',' + 
                                            'CAST([' + Name+ '] AS ' + 'NVARCHAR(MAX)' + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME('Test'+'4')+ ',' + 
                                            'CAST([' + Name+ '] AS ' + 'NVARCHAR(MAX)' + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME('Test'+'5')+ ', '  
                FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5....
```

I would need to use only one time `'CAST([' + Name+ '] AS ' + 'NVARCHAR(MAX)' + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME('Test'+'1')+ ','` but problem is that I don't know how to make different names for each columns, in this case all columns will be names `Test1`

Comment: mysql or sqlserver? I would suggest you to unpivot and then pivot again... but can you select unique records before your first pivot?

Comment: I dont think it is achievable.

Comment: How does the table look (definition and sample data.) Unique columns? Which dbms are you using - MySQL or MS SQL Server - or both?

Comment: Thank you for an answers. I have updated my question with my select

Comment: Its SQL-server. Edited my tags, added by mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
select distinct id, name from [table]
```

or

```
select id, name from [table] group by id, name
```

Here distinct operator is for removing duplicate result rows.

Distinct is a pretty expensive operation, since, after processing the query, the DB server might perform a sort operation in order to remove the duplicates.